Data Cloud & Marketing Cloud Engagement - Activating to a single MC BU
Is anyone aware of any nuances or restrictions associated with triggering journeys using Data Actions from both a DC sandbox org and DC production org to a single Marketing Cloud Engagement business unit?
I would like to trigger my journeys from the sanbox prior to prod.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
